# Characterization of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: analysis

If algebra can be characterized as the study of algebraic structures and the structure-preserving maps between them, how could we characterize mathematical analysis as a field? In analysis, can we break it down into certain mathematical structures, maybe topologies or metric spaces, and the continuous maps between them? Would this be the best way to characterize analysis?

Answer (score 1):

I really like this quote of Dieudonné (in french) : "L'analyse c'est minorer, majorer et approcher".

Comment: A translation could be : "Analysis is about find lower bounds, upper bounds and good approximations."

Answer (score 0):

While Nicolas answer is very good, I dont think it is very pedagogical. These upper bounds, lower bounds and approximations all really boil down to sequences!
 (which in turn are connected to toplogies)

So I would say structures related to "sequences" of different kinds i.e functions, real numbers or even operators. As for connecting to your question, continous maps preserve toplogies and hence sequences.

So from a "structural" point of view, the answer I think is sequences.